# Why does the law of diminishing returns imply that the set of commodity bundles preferable to $\vec{x}_0$ is convex?

Tags: mathematical-economics

To clarify notation in what follows, both $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{x}_0$ are *bundles of commodities*, that is, vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the value in each coordinate represents the quantity of the commodity associated to such coordinate. Fixing an individual, one writes $\vec{x}\succ \vec{x}_0$ if the individual has a preference for $\vec{x}$ over $\vec{x}_0$, and one writes $\vec{x}\succeq \vec{x}_0$ if $\vec{x}\succ \vec{x}_0$ or if the individual is indifferent between the two bundles.

---

The following is an excerpt from Cassels' *Economics for Mathematicians*:

*It is a standard assumption in economics that for any $x_0$ the set
$$V(\vec{x}_0):=\{\vec{x}:\vec{x}\succeq\vec{x}_0\}$$
is convex. This may be regarded as a consequence of the "law of diminishing returns".*

---

Why does the law of diminishing returns imply that the set $V(\vec{x}_0)$ is convex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Edited a la comments]** **[Proof attempt]** We have a vector whose components are the real quantities of each good in a bundle of goods, $\vec{x_0} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We make standard neoclassical, [von Neumann-Morgenstein assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Morgenstern_utility_theorem#The_axioms) about the utility function, including that utility is a [monotonic transformation](https://www.uv.es/%7Econtrera/Angles/Micro%20I.%20Lesson%204.pdf) of preference relations and some appropriately continuous and differentiable function, $u(\vec{x}):\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. The indifference hypersurface<sup>1</sup> of $\vec{x_0}$ is defined as the set of bundles $V(\vec{x}_0):=\{\vec{x}:\vec{x}\succcurlyeq\vec{x}_0, \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$, where a preference relation $\vec{x}\succcurlyeq\vec{x}_0 \implies u(\vec{x})\geq u(\vec{x}_0)$. For any *rational* agent, given an arbitrary bundle $\vec{x_0}$, the indifference set $V$ is a [convex set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set) as an implication of the assumption that *marginal* utility experiences [diminishing marginal returns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_utility#Law_of_diminishing_marginal_utility).

Let $\vec{x_i} \in V(\vec{x_0})$. Now, $\vec{x_i} \succcurlyeq \vec{x_0}$ and so $u(\vec{x_i}) \geq u(\vec{x_0}).$
From diminishing marginal utility assumptions, utility is concave in quantity with respect to the origin, $\frac{\delta^2u}{\delta\textbf{x}^2} < 0$ (or the hessian is negative-definite or $u''(\vec{x}) < 0$). As an implication of this, for any two arbitrary indices, $j,k \in \{1, \dots, |V|\}$, and some $\alpha \in [0,1]$, we have that the first utility weak inequality below is preserved:

\begin{align}
u(\alpha \vec{x_j} + (1-\alpha)\vec{x_k}) &\geq u(\vec{x_j} + 0\cdot \vec{x_k}) \\
&\geq u( 0\cdot\vec{x_j} + \vec{x_k}) \\
& \geq u(\vec{x_j}) \\
& \geq u(\vec{x_0}) \\
\Big(\alpha \vec{x_j} + (1-\alpha)\vec{x_k}\Big) &\succcurlyeq \vec{x_0}\\
\implies \Big(\alpha \vec{x_j} + (1-\alpha)\vec{x_k}\Big) &\in V(\vec{x_0})\\
\implies V \text{ is a convex set.} \blacksquare
\end{align}

For any two arbitrary bundles in the preferred set $V$, any affine combination of them is at least as utile as maintaining the quantities in one bundle and setting the other to zero. And by extension, such a combination bundle is at least as utile as the $\vec{x_0}$ bundle. If utility is concave in quantities, an utility-preserving indifference hypersurface of quantities is convex.

---

[1] *(1.8) The condition [$\vec{x}\succ\vec{x}_0 \implies u(\vec{x})> u(\vec{x}_0)$] implies that the set $u(\vec{x}) = constant$ is a hypersurface... called an indifference hypersurface. (Cassels, 1981, p. 1)*

---

**[My intuition]** As a simplified 2D analog, imagine the quantity of one good as $x_0$  and the quantity of another good that yields the same utility as $x_1 = V(x_0)$. Here, it is easy to see that the plots of all combinations of $(x_0, x_1)$ is convex to the origin because of the law of diminishing marginal returns. Low but non-trivial quantities of either good yield the same utility as very high quantities of one good and very low quantities of the other because utility as a function of quantity is concave. Any new coordinate is an affine combination of other quantity coordinates on the curve (ie a point on the line connecting the two coordinates) and preserves the utility level $u(x_0, x_1)$, ie remains on or inside the curve (in other words, $V$ is a convex set).

[image]([Source](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/29584/42422))

We can generalize this idea up to vectors of quantities "on either axis", ie bundles, rather than single-good scalars. Any quantity bundle that is an affine combination of indifferent quantity bundles preserves utility which means that such a combination bundle is also preferred or indifferent to $\vec{x_0}$. So, any affine combination of indifferent bundles remains on the indifference hyperspace or inside the region bounded by it (ie convex set).

Comment: What's the "law of diminishing returns"?

Comment: What does $u'(\vec x)$ mean? The derivative of $u$ with respect to the *vector* $\vec x$? Or some particular element of that vector? You should also doublecheck your definition of "diminishing marginal returns". It should be about $u''$ not $u'$.

Comment: I think that your proof works, but you have to make it more precise. First, you have to specify the space in which you work, I guess $\mathbb{R^n}$,   and make more explicit your assumptions. In your proof you use a utility function, so you have a function $u$ of several variable, and therefore  you have to speak of partial derivatives (supposing that $u$ is differentiable as necessary). Then, I guess that you assume that the utility function is concave. You have to make explicit, in mathematical terms,  what do you mean by ‘law of  iminishing returns’, it should be about the hessian of $u$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, I meant the hessian is negative definite, and $u'$ is a typo that's been fixed. Have edited to make it more precise.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to make any assumptions about the existence of a utility representation to show this. The law of diminishing returns is usually defined as the assumption that the preference relation $\succcurlyeq$ is [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_preferences). Convex preferences satisfy the following equation: $$y \succcurlyeq x, z \succcurlyeq x \implies \forall \theta \in [0, 1], \theta y + (1 - \theta) z \succcurlyeq x$$

Fix a bundle $x_0$ and consider its upper contour set $V(x_0)$. Let $x_1, x_2$ be chosen such that $x_1 \succcurlyeq x_0$ and $x_2 \succcurlyeq x_0$. Then by the definition of convexity above, $\forall \theta \in [0, 1], \theta x_1 + (1 - \theta) x_2 \succcurlyeq x_0$, and so $\theta x_1 + (1 - \theta) x_2 \in V(x_0)$.

Thus, we have shown $x_1, x_2 \in V(x_0) \implies \theta x_1 + (1 - \theta) x_2 \in V(x_0)$, which is exactly the definition of a set being convex.

Comment: I think this is a neat way to define your way to it, but I think OP wants a proof of the following claim:

"That the assumption that marginal utilitity experiences diminishing returns is equivalent to the assumption that the preference relation, fixed at any arbitrary value, maps an indifference set that is convex."